# Migrate from Initramfs-tools to Dracut

Tags: linux, debian, dracut

I have a question about migrating fron "Initramfs-tool" to "Dracut".

Initramfs-tools relies on customization scripts hosted by the folders "/etc/initramfs-tools/" and "/usr/share/initramfs-tools/".

"Dracut" relies on customization modules hosted by "/etc/dracut.conf.d/" folder.

I have a lot of initramfs scripts, so a I ask me: will [upgrading to dracut](https://www.pcsuggest.com/dracut-linux-ubuntu/) break those scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitively solved my problem rewriting my scripts for Dracut.

The solution [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/antonio-petricca/buddy-linux).